Which position on a vehicle is least effected by the steering?
I am looking to position a paint sprayer for longitudinal lines on the roads. The plant I have is three wheeled the single wheel is at the front and dual at the back. It has the options to have the spray gun near the front or rear wheels off to the right or left side. The front wheel turns for steering.
Where on this three wheeled plant should I have the guns mounted to have the least deviation from straight or affects from the steering on the sprayed straight line. This needs to be outside the vehicle the vehicle dimensions are as follows 2.8m long by 880mm wide. The guns can be positioned out wider than the vehicle about 600mm
A second part of the question is where on a four wheeled vehicle is the best place to mount for the same reason. Does the length of the vehicle matter?
I looked forward to hearing your answers.

wouldn't that be next to the back wheel?

Ideally between the two rear wheels on the centreline of the vehicle.
This needs to be outside the vehicle the vehicle dimensions are as follows 2.8m long by 880mm wide. The guns can be positioned out wider than the vehicle about 600mm
Laterally spacing them is bad, so it looks as though you'll be hanging them off the back in the middle. It would of course be fairly simple to design a mechanism to move the gun to compensate for the steering.
Same applies for a 4 wheeled vehicle.

The line sprayers exist and work well. Don't think I have ever seen one painting at the rear though. Crop sprayers though yes.

I agree, but that wasn't the question. Consider a tricycle with a sinusoidal steering input. The front of the vehicle veers from left to right, the middle of the rear axle traces a straight line. Of course a competent driver can keep a front mounted sprayer on track, but that is not what was asked.

straight, or at least straighter. Essentially the rear axle's path is an integrator (low pass filter) of the front steer angle
